# Bootstrap File Input com asp.net MVC

Tags: file-upload, multiple-file-upload

Estou utilizando o Bootstrap File Input (http://plugins.krajee.com/file-advanced-usage-demo) no meu projeto Asp.Net MVC mas ele possui um bug que quando adiciono algum arquivo e depois acrescento outro ele continua exibindo na tela todos mas só posta os últimos arquivos adicionados. Alguém já passou por isso e conseguiu solucionar ? O máximo que cheguei foi no método $("#File").fileinput('getFileStack') que retorna um array dos arquivos mas também não estou conseguindo postar esse array para o server. Fico no aguardo. Obrigado.

Abaixo segue o trecho da View onde está o upload.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ContaPagar", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.File, new { type = "file", multiple = "true", @accept = "application/pdf", @class= "file", @id= "File", Name = "File" })
                    <br>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 pull-right form-group">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button id="btnSalvar" name="btnSalvar" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar Pagamento</button>
                    </div>
                </div>                
                }
```

E no server eu apanho os arquivos através do `Request.Files`. O problema ocorre que quando adiciono arquivos e acrescento outros depois (Ex.: Adiciono 2 .pdf e depois mais 3 .pdf totalizando 3) ele só posta os últimos adicionados.

Comment: o ideal seria você postar os códigos que você tem, de De View, model e controller, para facilitar a identificação do erro

Comment: O problema pode ser como está resgatando as informações, poste o seu código do `controller` e sua `view` sem isso fica dificil definir uma resposta